# How to save streamed Flash (SWF) files

Tags: internet, flash, swf

I know how to save Flash (swf) files with or without software and on different web browsers, but there are some files which load (stream) the data (may be a certain set of frames) from their web server or stuff like that, so when we save them they don't run... like some online   Flash games or some Flash based websites.

Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: It might help if you could give an example.

Comment: example of what

Comment: An example of what exactly you would like to download or save.

Comment: http://www.elsemobile.com/#/Touch/ThesPlay after skipping the intro and entering the site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible way is to install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which acts as a proxy on your own computer. When you'll set it as a default proxy in your browser all connections will go through it, including every Flash connection. Then you can save all the files the Flash applet requests and place it on a locally-installed webserver in appropriate directories.

Probably this is the only way to "save", i.e. duplicate functionality of sites with such dynamically loaded content.

There may be troubles with a e.g. game which stores its level data in different files for each level and loads them when you unlock that level, but you can try guessing file names in such a case.

Comment: lemme try it...

Comment: i have used it.. but i cannot save the swf files.. all it lets me save are the sessions and stupid text files... little help please

Comment: @Moon Fiddler will assist in finding what you have to download and how to recreate the structure to make it work once you have downloaded via normal means. Fiddler won't download the SWF's for you, it's a tool use to determine what connect where and what happens in the background with a particular web connection.

Comment: Thanks @Diago, I somehow missed that reply. Yes, Fiddler just consolidates the data your browser is downloading; it cannot magically determine what files are required by some applet, but it can show what files were *actually downloaded* by that applet.

Answer (score -1):

If the game or site pulls data from other places on the web, I don't know that this is possible.

If it's not pulling data from other places, [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006/) for Firefox works great.

Comment: people please read the question again

Answer (score -1):

Use Video Download helper, Unplug and Embedded Objects 2.6.

Those extensions can download almost any Flash thing from any website you visit with Firefox. However, only Flash files that are actually stored on a server can be played on your computer. Live streams won't work if you download them to your computer.

Comment: i think you need to read the question again

Comment: @Moon sorry for adding too much info about the topic in general thought they might be useful :) .. and as i said from my experience STREAMS cant run on ur pc unless u can get all the stream files and save them in directories at the same range (directoryNames and arrangemt) that is on the server (and saving the stream files isnt going to help if that stream is of the LiVe streams)

Comment: thats exactly my point.... no matter stream or anything... all the data that is required to display something on the screen is downloaded to the pc then displayed... call it a streamed video, web page, dynamic web page, flash game, flash video, streamed flash game, streamed flash video etc.. its going to be downloaded to your pc. and after use its discarded.. its just that is there a way to store... not record it.... store the actual data in its true format... streamed flash files are just downloaded frames and object and sprites and everything thatmakes a flash file